# Exporting pooled GEE estimates from the `mi` package

Tags: r, missing-data, r-mice

I'm doing some regression using the `geepack` package and want to use multiple imputation to deal with missing values. The `pool()` command in `mi` doesn't work for my GEE, so I have to export (is that right?) so that I can use the data in `geepack`.
The `complete()` function produces each iteration, but not the pooled estimates.
Is there a way to produce a data frame with the pooled estimates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `complete` function in the mi package produces a list of `m` data.frames. You can call `gee` on each element of that list for the `data` argument and then use Rubin's rules to obtain pooled estimates.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple if packages that implement Rubin's rules in R (e.g., `mi`, `mice`, `mitools`, and `mitml`). The problem is that these implementation require that the functions for fitting statistical models have working methods for `coef()` and `vcov()` defined.

The `geeglm()` function, however, does not define `vcov()`, and standard implementations will not work. To remedy that situation, it is easiest to just define the missing method for the GEE. Below is an example using the `mitml` package and one of the example data sets provided with `geepack`.

```
library(geepack)
library(mitml)

# example data
data(dietox)

# example imputation
fml <- Feed + Weight ~ 1 + Time + (1|Pig)
imp <- panImpute(data=dietox, formula=fml, n.burn=5000, n.iter=500)

implist <- mitmlComplete(imp, "all")

# fit GEE
fit <- with(implist, geeglm(Weight ~ 1 + Time + Feed, id=Pig))

# define missing vcov() function for geeglm-objects
vcov.geeglm <- function(x) summary(x)$cov.scaled

# combine estimates using Rubin's rules
testEstimates(fit)
```